# How To Install Froyo on HTC Bravo

Tags: htc-desire, rom-flashing, downgrade

I have an HTC Bravo. Some time ago I installed Gingerbread on it and started to have trouble. If I connect to the Internet or do some memory intensive work it resets itself. Now I want to install Froyo again on my Bravo.

Can somebody guide me in the right direction, or did I burn too many bridges to go back?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can install Revolutionary, and choose the option to install the Clockwork Recovery Mod, look for a copy of the original Froyo rom from somewhere and then use Recovery to put it back on your phone?

Of course, while you're doing that you could check out CyanogenMod v7.1 and see if that gives you what you need.

Comment: I'll second trying CM-7.1 for bravo (HTC Desire). It has >100k CM  users and is probably still the most stable device for CM7.